# How to document callback parameters in JSDoc for Visual Studio intellisense?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017, jsdoc

I just cannot figure out how to correctly document callback using `@param` so that Visual Studio 2017 intellisense will understand it.

For example:

```
/**
 * @param {string} file absolute path
 * @param {Function} callback called when done
*/
function loadFile(path, callback) {
    /// code
}
```

The callback accepts `Error` and `string` as arguments (Node.js style), how to document it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This pattern works:

```
/**
 * @param {string} file absolute path
 * @param {function(Error, string):void} callback called when done
*/
function loadFile(path, callback) {
    /// code
}
```

`void` here stands for no return value, can be replaced with callback return value (eg.: `{function(value):boolean}` for a predicate).

How to document parameter names I do not know.

Comment: OMG you are my hero, @tomáš-zato .  I tried using the official JSDoc notation for callbacks and nothing worked until I saw this.  I wish I could upvote this answer multiple times.

Comment: Bonus if you can figure out how to annotate the parameters with variable names and descriptions!

Comment: @KrisOye I wish. I tried all kinds of combinations without success.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the name of the parameters too along with the types?

Comment: @tonix Not that I know of. You could probably define dummy function somewhere and refer to it as it were a type.

Comment: you sir are my hero

Answer (score 5):

To annotate the callback parameters with types and names, do this:

```
/**
 * @param {string} path - absolute file path
 * @param {(error: string, namedParameter: type)} callback - callback called when done
*/
function loadFile(path, callback) {
  /// code
}
```